# how to upload a large size file in chunks on server in php?

Tags: php, file-upload

How do I divide a large file in chunks and upload it to server?

I try the simple `move_uploaded_file()` function but it upload only of 2 MB size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

increase upload maximum file size limit with this method :

**Method # 1: Edit php.ini**

Edit your php.ini file (usually stored in /etc/php.ini or /etc/php.d/cgi/php.ini or /usr/local/etc/php.ini):

```
# vi /etc/php.ini
```

Sample outputs:

```
memory_limit = 32M
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 20M
```

Save and close the file. Restart apache or lighttpd web server:

[service httpd restart](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/star-stop-restart-apache2-webserver/)

OR
[service lighttpd restart](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/stop-lighttpd-server/)

**Method #2: Edit .htaccess**

Edit .htaccess file in your root directory. This is useful when you do not have access to php.ini file. In this example, /home/httpd/html is considered as root directory (you can also create .htaccess file locally and than upload it using ftp / sftp / scp client):

```
# vi /home/httpd/html/.htaccess
```

Append / modify setting as follows:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 10M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value memory_limit 32M
```

Save and close the file.

**Method #3: Edit PHP File**

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

After this you can ckeck :

```
<?php
   phpinfo();
?>
```

check this for chunk upload 
[plupload](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload)

Comment: thnx for your answer but i want to upload it by dividing it in chunks and then after on server site want to combine it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a class that can help you to chunk big files using pattern strings and reassemble them at server level.

[The class](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/7960-PHP-Split-files-into-chunks-divided-by-pattern-strings.html)

As you don't mention what file format you are talking about the class will need some tweaking and testing for you to work.

Comment: Try http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2502-PHP-Split-files-in-pieces-that-can-be-gathered-later.html instead.

Answer (score -1):

try putting this code top of your code

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '10M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '10M');
ini_set('max_input_time', 300);
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can actually update your php ini to allow uploading larger files

```
Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 100M;

Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 100M;
```

But if you still need to upload huge files and chunking is a mandatory, there are lots of javascript implementation for this, one of them:

http://www.plupload.com/